# How Can I Some ImageView Add to relativeLayout

Tags: android, imageview, addition, android-relativelayout

I would like to add some ImageViews to a RelativeLayout view.

The code that I'm using is as follows:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        ArrayList<ImageView> icons = new ArrayList<ImageView>();

        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {

                ImageView imageView1 = new ImageView(G.context);
                imageView1.setImageResource(R.drawable.music_icon);
                imageView1.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                imageView1.getLayoutParams().width = (int) convertDpToPixel(20);
                imageView1.getLayoutParams().height = (int) convertDpToPixel(20);

                icons.add(imageView1);

                Log.i("LOG", "Icons Size: " + icons.size());
                Log.i("LOG", "I: " + i);

                relativeLayout.addView(icons.get(i));

                icons.get(i).startAnimation(animationMusic);

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(3000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    });
    thread.start();
```

The first time the loop runs fine, but the second time there's an error in the line:

```
relativeLayout.addView(icons.get(i));
```

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

One major problem is manipulating the view (e.g. adding a View) from a background thread.  You can get similar async behavior by making use of Android's AsyncTask objects and do any UI manipulation from the onPostExecute method.

Without know more about what you're doing, it's hard to find a solution that will work for you.  I was mainly pointing out a primary issue with your code.

Here is an attempt to rewrite your code in a way that might work better in an Android environment:

```
public void addImageViews() {
    for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        asyncAdd(i, G.context);
    }
}

protected void asyncAdd(final int index, final Context c) {
    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(3000 * index);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            relativeLayout.addView(generateImageView(c));
        }

    }.execute();
}

protected ImageView generateImageView(Context c) {
    ImageView imageView1 = new ImageView(c);
    imageView1.setImageResource(R.drawable.music_icon);
    imageView1.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    imageView1.getLayoutParams().width = (int) convertDpToPixel(20);
    imageView1.getLayoutParams().height = (int) convertDpToPixel(20);
    return imageView1;
}
```

Comment: Can you check an example?

Comment: Thank you dear friend. 
I tried your code and it was good. 
But I could not use my animation for imageView. Can you help?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with the animation?  This code as it is is a little weird, to be honest, putting images on top of each other and adding animations... There's probably a cleaner way to achieve what you're after.